# Can someone help me with this question? Please elaborate on how it eneded up as -1/6 .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I used symbolab for efficiency, however i came across this roadblock and i cannot move past. I it showed up that $\frac{1}{6}\left(2\cdot \frac{6+\sqrt{12\left(-1+4n\right)}}{8}-1\right)^3-n\frac{6+\sqrt{12\left(-1+4n\right)}}{8}$ was equal to $-\frac16$ and for the life of me i cannot find out why it is. I'd appreciate every bit of help i can get.

$\frac{1}{6}\left(2\cdot \frac{6+\sqrt{12\left(-1+4n\right)}}{8}-1\right)^3-n\frac{6+\sqrt{12\left(-1+4n\right)}}{8}=-\frac16$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 type your question rather than providing a link.

Comment: It is just long and tedious, but try doing whatever simplifications you can to begin with using parentheses when necessary.  E.g. the first step I would do is to replace the messy fraction with $x$ for the time being.  Then expand $(2x-1)^3$ as being $8x^3-12x^2+12x-1$.  You can then go and find $x^3$ and $x^2$ in terms of the messy fraction on the side before substituting those values back in.

Comment: It will help to remember that $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$ and that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$, for whatever messy expression you need to use for $a$ or $b$.  Beyond that however, no other special observations are necessary.  Its just a lot of messy tedious algebra...

Comment: Agree with @JMoravitz.  Also solve for $n$ in terms of $x$, so that $n=\frac{(4x-3)^2+3}{12}$

Comment: The expression is equal to $-1/6$, no?

Comment: @sharding4 could you elaborate on how you got there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When simplifying these kind of massive expressions, try renaming variables and achieving something simpler, tackling it little by little. In this particular case, set $x = (6+\sqrt{12(-1+4n)})/8$ and notice your expression is:

$$\frac{1}{6}(2x-1)^3-nx = - nx + \frac{4x^3}{3} - 2x^2 + x - \frac{1}{6}$$

Now notice:

$$x^3 = \frac{3n}{16}\sqrt{3(4n-1)} + \frac{27n}{16} + \frac{3}{8}\sqrt{3(4n-1)} $$

$$x^2 = \frac{3}{8} + \frac{3n}{4} + \frac{3}{8}\sqrt{3(4n-1)} $$

$$x = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{3(4n-1)} $$

Now, set $y = \sqrt{3(4n-1)}$. Can you rewrite the expression and finish the exercise?

**Hint:** Notice how the term $-nx$ cancels out with the first term from $4x^3/2$ and the first term of $-2x^2$ cancels out with the first term from $x$ (and similarly with the terms containing the lone $n$), so you only have an expression in terms of $y$ and a $-1/6$ at the end.

Comment: Thank you ! This really helped me understand it. Algebra isn't my forte